# Webapp installation incomplete in ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webapps

I published a little webapp for ubuntu touch:  [search.ch](https://launchpad.net/search.ch-webapp)

But for some reason the installation does not complete. You can start the app, but inside the store the app seems not to be installed.

In the [logfile (lines 14/15)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12137701/) I can see an issue with apparmor, but I don't know how to fix it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the package name needs to contain the official developer name.
Change *applicationName: "appname"* to *applicationName: "appname.developer"*